# Background worker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

If i have a set of actions i want to run in a background worker based on a certain condition and i have 10 conditions, for example

```
if(a)
    BackgroundWorker doA = new backgroundworker()
if(b) 
    BackgroundWorker doB = new backgroundworker()
if(c) 
    BackgroundWorker doC = new backgroundworker()
if(d) 
    BackgroundWorker doD = new backgroundworker()
...
...
```

each of those background workers will require a dowork, runworkercompleted etc.... is there anyway to avoid that so it makes the code less messy/clutered as some of those methods might be quite big?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)  from the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace instead, it's very simple and easy to use.

To start a task, you can simply use: `Task.Factory.StartNew()` passing a method or a lambda expression as a parameter. you get back a `Task` object that you can use for continuation, getting the result back, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using a single backgroundworker and passing an argument to it.Using this argument in the DoWork method you can determine which block of code to work.Check this thread

[Sending Arguments To Background Worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4807152/217880)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass in the object that needs evaluating to the BackgroundWorker and the BackgroundWorker can use it to determine what to do?