# DoWork of BackgroundWorker is called twice when RunWorkerAsync is called once?

Tags: c#

I have create a backgroundworker in an class it works, but if i call and wait until the end run, call it for the second time it will do the same process twice

i thinks there is somthing wrong with **bw.DoWork +=**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    nptest.test.start("null", "null");    
}


namespace nptest
{
    class test
    {
        public static void start(string str, string strb)
        {
            if (bw.IsBusy != true)
            {
                bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                bw.DoWork += (obj, e) => bw_DoWork(str, strb);
                bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
        private static BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        private static void bw_DoWork(string str, string strb)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("initializing BackgroundWorker");
        }
        private static void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Cancelled == true))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Canceled");
            }
            else if (!(e.Error == null))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
            }
            bw.Dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

**problem solved**

```
  class test
    {
        private static List<object> arguments = new List<object>();

        // initializing with program startup
        public static void bwinitializing()
        {
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }

        public static void start(string str, string strb)
        {
            if (bw.IsBusy != true)
            {
                arguments.Clear();
                arguments.Add(str);
                arguments.Add(strb);
                bw.RunWorkerAsync(arguments);
            }
        }
        private static BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        private static void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            List<object> genericlist = e.Argument as List<object>;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("BackgroundWorker " + genericlist[0]);

        }
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable that if you call a function twice it will do the same thing twice. What is your question? Why do you think the behaviour is incorrect?

Comment: if you call funciton twice it will execute code twice.. what else do you expect ?

Comment: I only click the button once why it does the process twice

Comment: Friendly warning: *do not* access UI components inside the "DoWork" event.

Comment: @pst, im sorry i don't get it

Comment: @Power-Mosfet I believe a more reasonable title/problem description would be "DoWork of BackgroundWorker is called twice when RunWorkerAsync is called once?" If so, consider using and/or adapting it to better represent the problem at hand. I have not made the edit myself since I am not 100% certain this is the problem that is being observed.

Comment: @Power-Mosfet if you add a background worker via designer, it automatically adds the .DoWork += assignment. If you then add it again in your code, that'll cause the DoWork function to get called twice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have encounter same problem as above commenter "Power-Mosfet"

and in the end, added a `new BackgroundWorker()` then assigned to the global bw value will fix my problem.

code is, change from:

```
private BackgroundWorker gBgwDownload;

private void yourFunction_bw(xxx)
{
    // Create a background thread
    gBgwDownload.DoWork += bgwDownload_DoWork;
    gBgwDownload.RunWorkerCompleted += bgwDownload_RunWorkerCompleted;
    //omited some code
    gBgwDownload.RunWorkerAsync(paraObj);
}
```

to:

```
private BackgroundWorker gBgwDownload;

private void yourFunction_bw(xxx)
{
    // Create a background thread
    gBgwDownload = new BackgroundWorker(); /* added this line will fix problem */
    gBgwDownload.DoWork += bgwDownload_DoWork;
    gBgwDownload.RunWorkerCompleted += bgwDownload_RunWorkerCompleted;
    //omited some code
    gBgwDownload.RunWorkerAsync(paraObj);

}
```

Comment: crifan you are a hero, that also fixed my issue.

Answer (score 16):

I would suspect that *multiple* `DoWork` events are being inadvertently added.

That is, *every time* the `start` method is called it registers a *new* `DoWork` event handler. This *adds* and does *not replace* the existing handler `DoWork` handler. So then there will be multiple `DoWork` handlers called subsequent times .. 1, 2, 3, etc.

```
// creates a NEW delegate and adds a NEW handler
bw.DoWork += (obj, e) => bw_DoWork(str, strb);
```

I would recommend *not* using a closure here, but rather just use a Method Group (with implicit conversion to a delegate) and then pass the data to the `RunWorkerAsync` call (there is a form that takes an argument for data).

The `RunWorkerCompleted +=` line doesn't have this issue because it is passed a delegate from a Method Group (which is guaranteed to always evaluate to the same delegate object<sup>1</sup>). Thus the repeated `+=` calls for that line *will* replace the handler.

---

Example:

```
class MyData {
   public string StrA { get; set; }
}

// These only need to be setup once (and should be for clarity).
// However it will be "ok" now if they are called multiple times
// as, since the delegates are the same, the += will
// act as a replacement (as it replaces the previous delegate with itself).
bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;

// Pass data via argument
bw.RunWorkerAsync(new MyData {
    StrA = str,
});

void bw_DoWork (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    var data = (MyData)e.Argument;
    var str = data.StrA;
    // stuff
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I am not sure if it is guaranteed to be reference-equals equality, but using this approach allows for stable invoking of `+=` and `-=` from the delegate from the Method Group even if obtained by `new DelegateType(MethodGroup)`.

Wrt. my comment in the main post: if UI elements are accessed from a thread on which they were *not* created then there will fun "Cross-thread operation exceptions". I believe this usage of a Message Box is "okay" (when not created with an owner from another thread), but the practice of accessing the UI in a BackgroundWorker's DoWork is generally dubious.

---

Also, *do not* call `bw.Dispose()` here; dispose it with the owning container or context. It appears to be nice and benign in this case, but only do it when that BGW instance will *never* be used again. Calling it from an event handler is also dubious as the BGW is still "active".

Comment: @Power-Mosfet Now, that is something I do *not* expect to happen with the above recommendations :) Just to clarify, the `DoWork` is called *multiple times* for *each* click event that occurs?

Comment: @Power-Mosfet My modifications above should ensure that it does not happen. Make sure that the *only* line adding the `DoWork` handlers is `bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;` and there is *not* another `DoWork += ..` hiding somewhere tricky. If this modification is made then the `DoWord+=` can (and likely should) also be moved to the `test` class constructor. Also make sure that the project is successfully rebuilt and the correct executable is being run -- this can be a tricky issue to find! Also see my later not about (not) using `Dispose()` here ..

Comment: I have created an new class copy paste your codesnap, rebuild the project with success and still the same effect. I have also remove the Dispose()

Comment: @Power-Mosfet - did you just copy and paste the entire code into the `Start` method? Did you read and follow the `//` comments in this answer?

Answer (score 5):

There is also another reason. look for `DoWorkEventHandler` in its generated code `InitializeComponent()` If you have generated it through compnent UI properties and also registering it yourself.

Because if you register it again it will not override the previous one but will add another event and will call twice.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, BackgroundWorker was running twice because in the constructor class of my form I declared the DoWork, ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted event handlers, but it was already declared by Visual Studio 2013 in Designer part of this form class.

So, I just deleted my declarations and it worked fine.

Comment: Same for me, I copied pasted the "addHandler" lines from internet, and this made the multiple calls.Removing those lines did the trick

Answer (score 0):

thank you....this code is working fine... creating new intance for backroundworker is good idea....
Now we can call this function in for/while loop and can run multiple backgroundworker process.

I coded like this
when button click is done.. without distrubting the main thread flow... multiple process will be running back side....
i just used messagebox to pop up..but we can do timetaking process to run in "bgwDownload_DoWork" function... and multiple process will be created... and her we need not check the BackgroundWorker is busy or not...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     yourFunction_bw(i);

 }
private BackgroundWorker gBgwDownload;

private void yourFunction_bw(int i)
{
    // Create a background thread
    gBgwDownload = new BackgroundWorker(); // added this line will fix problem 
    gBgwDownload.DoWork += bgwDownload_DoWork;
    gBgwDownload.RunWorkerAsync(i);

}

private void bgwDownload_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  int stre = (int)e.Argument;
  MessageBox.Show(stre.ToString ()); // time taken process can be added here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today, I put a background worker on a popup form that was doing a long running task when I noticed that every time I showed the form the background worker RunWorkerCompleted event was being called multiple times.

My problem was that I was not disposing of the form after closing it, which meant every time I showed the form it added another handler to the even each time.

Disposing of the form when finished with it solved my problem. Just wanted to mention it here as I came across this page when I went looking for a solution for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the control from the designer and instantiate a new WorkerProcess in Code:

example:
 var bwProcess = new BackgroundWorker();

bwProcess.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bwProcess_DoWork);

bwProcess.RunWorkerCompleted += bwProcess_RunWorkerCompleted;