# C# Backgroundworker keep on running DoWork

Tags: c#

Below is my coding:

```
    Form2 msgForm;
    private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);

        msgForm = new Form2();

        try
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();

            msgForm.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Coding that transmit protocol and will last around 2 minutes.
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        msgForm.Close();
    }
```

I use the background worker method everytime I click a button to transmit protocols that last around 2 minutes. During transmission, the From2 will show 'Please wait'.

But I have some problem using this coding. The problem is like, when I click the button the first time, it will transmit the protocol once. After that I click again which is the second time, it transmit the protocol twice. After that I click again which is the third time, it transmit the protocol 3 times.... And so on. The times of protocol of transmit increase each time I click the button.

Aren't that it will only run once the coding in void bw_DoWork everytime I click the button?

Is there something wrong with my coding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're appending an *additional* handler every time you click, and then it's run *along with everything you added before*, which stays where it is (because the object is still there, you're re-using it).

To solve this, you need to either:

- Move the declaration of the background worker inside the method (so it's new every time, with only one `DoWork` handler

Like this:

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    // rest of your code
}
```

- Move the `.DoWork += ...` which appends the handler in the constructor of the class

It mostly depends on if you use that worker somewhere else.

Comment: No Alex. I just use the worker in transmitting protocol only.

Comment: Then declare it inside the method.

Comment: Alex, what do you mean by moving the declaration of the background worker inside the method?

Comment: he says you are doing `bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork)` once per every CLICK. you should not. You should do the += only ONCE at all.

Comment: if you want to do it once per click, then unlink the old handler first: `bw.DoWork -= new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork); bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);` but it is pointless in your case. you do not need to attach the handler again and again if it doesnt change at all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a new worker starts on every click.
To avoid this behaviour, check if the worker is busy before starting it again.

```
try
{
    if (!bw.IsBusy)
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

And you can disable the button while the backgroundworker does its job, by `button3.Enabled = false;` and re-enable it in the `bw_RunWorkerCompleted` method, letting the user understand he has to wait and cannot click again until the process is finished.

Comment: Nope. He's appending another handler every time.

Comment: @Alex I double checked the question and you're right, I missed that point. Upvoted your answer. Anyway, I believe it's a good idea to check if the BackgroundWorker is already running and enabling/disabling buttons accordingly =)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your lists/Collections are clear before transmit codes.
Then Use BreakPoint in your source code and remember that your BackgroundWorker can't run twice or more because you use ShowDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the worker is busy:

```
    if (!bw.IsBusy)         
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

I would also disable the button and change the text to for example 'Running' while the process is being excecuted.

Use the bw_RunWorkerCompleted method event call to then re-enable the button and change the text. This method runs on the same thread as the UI so there are no cross thread issues.

On your design, why are you showing another form for the 'Please wait' notification? I would suggest updating a label on your existing form either before the async process starts (so not cross thread UI issues) or if you need to update after then you can use the following:

```
lblNotify.Invoke(new Action(() => lblNotify.Text = @"Please wait"));
```

The above will then allow you to run your request on the main thread.