# Polymorphic way to call different functions with an allocated thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, plugins, scheduled-tasks, mef

I have a `class` with a set of functions that differ in the number of parameters and the parameter types.  I've been trying to figure out a way to invoke a call to a desired function inside an allocated thread.

What's a simple way of doing this?  I've looked into `System.Action`, but that requires the parameters to be known.  I've also gone over `TaskFactory` and `TPL`, but from the examples I've seen, I can't put together the solution in my head.

What I want to eventually do is queue up jobs that will be executed by a limited number of threads.  The jobs performed are simple `HTTP` requests.

I feel like this has been done before and has a simple solution, but it has eluded me for weeks.  I'm hoping for an elegant way of doing it instead of a lot of complex code.

I'm also trying to implement `MEF` plugins to make matters worse.

```
    public bool AddThreads(int numOfThreads)
    {
        try
        {
            // Exit if no plugin type is set
            if (PluginType == "") return false;

            int totalThreads = numOfThreads + threads.Count;
            for (int i = threads.Count; i < totalThreads; i++)
            {
                // Create an instance of the MEF plugin
                var task = PluginHandler.CreateInstance(PluginType);
                threads.Add(task);

                task.ThreadId = i;

                task.OnStatusChange += new TaskerPlugin.EventHandler(ChangeStatus);
                task.OnActionComplete += new TaskerPlugin.EventHandler(ReportComplete);
                task.OnActionSuccess += new TaskerPlugin.EventHandler(ReportSuccess);
                task.OnActionFailure += new TaskerPlugin.EventHandler(ReportFailure);
                task.OnActionAttempt += new TaskerPlugin.EventHandler(ReportAttempt);
                task.OnActionError += new TaskerPlugin.EventHandler(ReportError);
                task.OnActionCancelled += new TaskerPlugin.EventHandler(ReportCancellation);
                task.OnActionBegin += new TaskerPlugin.EventHandler(ReportStartOfTask);
                task.OnActionEnd += new TaskerPlugin.EventHandler(ReportEndOfTask);

                // Do work from plugin
                // This is where I'd like to call different 
                // functions possibly inside Start()
                task.Start();
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Current code calling the function:

```
    private void CreateThreads(int threadCount)
    {
        // taskMan is a class variable to queue more jobs in the future
        taskMan = new TaskManager(PLUGIN_FOLDER)
        {
            PluginType = PLUGIN_TYPE,
            UseProxies = (_config.IpSolution == "Proxies" || _config.IpSolution == "Proxy URL")
        };

        taskMan.AddThreads(threadCount);
    }
```

I want to eventually just call a function to add a job to it with a predefined number of threads:

```
private void AddJob(string pluginName, string methodName, List<string> args)
```

I'd prefer not just using a string list to put all of my arguments in, but I don't really know of another way of doing it. Maybe a list of objects which I then cast later? Both these ideas are very messy...

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Yes, I can!  It's a bit ugly with all the events, though.

Comment: Have you tried using a BackgroundWorker? It allows you to pass an object paramter to itself, perhaps that might help you.. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4807200/1508398

Comment: Can you add sample method-call (s) that you want to make happen to your class's object?

Comment: Added the code I have calling the AddThreads function.  What I have currently will work if all I want is to do one thing over and over, but I want to be able to call other functions inside my plugin, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that `AddJob` is the overloaded method that you need to call with different parameters.

You might have to tweak your `PluginHandler.CreateInstance(PluginType)` method to do something like this while creating the task, this would allow you to execute any method you need in the task that you create..

```
Task task = new Task(() =>
{
    classInstance.YourMethod("some param1", some other param2));
}
```

Further with some reflection..

```
var classInstance = new YourClass();
Type type = classInstance.GetType();
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("AddJob");
object[] parametersArray = new object[] { "some param1", "some parma2" };
methodInfo.Invoke(methodInfo, parametersArray);
```

and finally,

```
Task task = new Task(() =>
{
    var classInstance = new YourClass();
    Type type = classInstance.GetType();
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("AddJob");
    object[] parametersArray = new object[] { "some param1", "some parma2" };
    methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray);
}
```

In case the `AddJob` method is present in the current `class` itself, there could be little changes to the code.