# Background worker does not Work WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

In my WPF program it took huge processing time and freezing for long time.

so I decided to use background worker and process it in background.

but it does not work. through debug, the program stop at `Render3D()`. It does not throw exception. Its like when you put `return`.

In other word it does nothing after reaching `Render3D()` and will just return.

(I don't say it will return Because im not sure but the behavior is same as return)

```
    private readonly BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    private AssetDeclaration _assetDeclaration = new AssetDeclaration();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            if (!((BackgroundWorker)sender).CancellationPending)
            {
                Render3D(); // will return at this point. (why?) or waiting for something to start?
                ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(i);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");//will show message box instant.
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //...Some work here before starting Hard job!
        //...From now i want to start heavy process in background.
        //...with report to progress bar at same time.
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(100);
    }
```

Render3D() works fine without Background processing but will freeze for some time.

Render3D() is in `Partial` class of `MainWindow` .because there are lots of methods so i decided to separate them.

Also how can I use `ReportProgress` outside `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` . for example in Render3D().

Last thing : i want to know how to show the user how much of process is done.

**Solved!:**

The problem was because i set `Viewport3D` inside `Render3D()`

I separated it from Render3D and problem got fixed. thanks to Henk Holterman for the right answer.

It seems some tasks cant be done in another Thread. with the Error report i find out that the invalid task is setting Viewport3D properties.

this tasks must be done in Main thread.

below is invalid Code that made background worker stop functioning.

```
DefineCamera();
Viewport.Children.Add(model); // Must be run in Main thread.
```

And this Part.

```
    private void DefineCamera()
    {
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera
        {
            FieldOfView = 60
        };

        PositionCamera(camera);
        Viewport.Camera = camera; // Must be run in Main thread.
    }
```

Comment: You don't have a Completed event. Add it and process the incoming `e.Error`. Or just add a try/catch to DoWork. You are now ignoring the exception that could tell you what went wrong.

Comment: "after i added RunWorkerCompleted" Ok, now make it report `e.Error`.

Comment: Check [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4807200/60761) for a canonical Completed event.

Comment: oh yes it shown Error. System.InvalidOperationException the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it @HenkHolterman

Comment: OK, Render3D() is not suitable for running on a Thread. End of exercise.

Comment: I'm with henk on this, what is the reason for moving render to a separate thread - anything render based should be on the UI thread?

Comment: what? . whitch part is not suitable? i have wrote it all my self. i used xml reader ,vector3d,vector ,point3d, color,quaternion and some other classes witch part is not suitable i did not understand and final model will render into viewport3d @HenkHolterman

Comment: We can't comment on / analyze code we can't see. The ViewPort won't be safe to use. Maybe you can split the GUI / non-GUI code, I can't tell.

Comment: i dont know. without this program will freeze and not-respond for moment i want to prevent this. @kidshaw

Comment: +1 thanks. ill try to split non GUI part. drawing model only takes milliseconds .so this may fix the problem @HenkHolterman

Comment: you were Right Henk. Problem got Fixed. the problem was because i set ViewPort inside Render3D() and thats why i got this exception :the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. please answer this this question because you find the answer. @HenkHolterman

Comment: Does it run if you comment out the call to Render3D()? If so, Render3D() expects to be run on the Main thread, rather than a worker thread: in which case you cannot fork that operation to a worker thread.

Comment: this question is already answered by HenkHolterman in comments but i cant mark it as answer! yes . i moved out the part that initialize ViewPort3D from render3D(). so the model gets ready in render3D() and will draw in another method. @PhillipNgan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you had trouble finding the error.

> ... the program stop at Render3D(). It does not throw exception. Its like when you put return.

What actually happened was that an exception was thrown by your method and was captured by the Backgroundworker. It is transferred to the Completed event but you do have to act on it there.

```
private void worker_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
  // check error, check cancel, then use result
  if (e.Error != null)
  {
     // handle the error
  }
  else if (e.Cancelled)
  {
     // handle cancellation
  }
  else      
  {         
      // use the result(s) on the UI thread
  }    
  // general cleanup
}
```

Failing to look at either `e.Error` or `e.Result` is the same as having an empty `catch{}` block in your program.

And with error handling in place we then have

> oh yes it shown Error. System.InvalidOperationException the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

This indicates that your Render3D() still interacts with the GUI somewhere.

The basic advice is to separate all the calculation (and I/O, database) work from the UI work. You can run the CPU bound and I/O bound cod in a thread but the GUI is single threaded, you can only interact with it from the main Thread.

Answer (score 0):

In the world of WPF, unlike Windows Forms that you were used to, you should consider **Dispatcher**. To do this, you have to import `System.Windows.Threading`

```
    private void ThreadTask()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    (ThreadStart)delegate()
                    {
                        //Do some heavy task here...
                    });
    }
```

**Quick Update**

In order to run the thread from a button click or whatever, any function, add this line of code:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadTask));
    thread.Start();
```

This line of code is equivalent to `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();`

Comment: Can someone explain why the down vote? I've used that before without any problem!

Comment: This makes no sense. Even when we ignore the Sleep(), the "heavy task" is sent back to the main Gui thread. No gain whatsoever. Just a confusing detour.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm not the only one to say thats the working solution. You can check the C# WPF documentation (I forgot what its name was).

Comment: It will work but it won't solve your freezing issue.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've been living with the dispatcher almost two years without any problem. I've used it for database app development (which is something that demands heavy tasks).

Comment: When you do the Db stuff in the place of the Sleep() then it's sort of OK. When you do it in the BeginInvoke then you've been doing it wrong all that time.

Comment: @user3104111: Like Henk says, you are completely ignoring the source of OP's problem.  This has nothing to do with using BackgroundWorker or not.  And if we're going to talk about best practices, then using Tasks and async would be superior to what you are suggesting, not to mention that you are creating individual threads rather than using the standard thread pool, and I could go on...

Comment: i tried it and it freeze again.as Henk said i think if i be able to split non GUI part then i can fix this problem ill work on it.

Answer (score -2):

I would highly recommend using async/await. This feature was introduced in .NET 4.5, and is used to shift work off the main WPF GUI thread to make the application fast and responsive.

Essentially, the rule is to push any calculations which do not interact with GUI onto a background thread using a combination of  **Task.Run** and **async/await**. Together with **Dispatcher.Invoke**, you don't really need anything else.

For example, a slow data call that might fetch data from the database could be pushed onto a background thread, so the application does freeze while it waits for the SQL to execute.

I've used this to make the applications that I write fast, responsive and snappy.

Comment: None of this addresses the problems the OP is facing.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm recommending a refactor to use async/await. This would fix the problems experienced by the OP.

Comment: No, it will suffer the same exception. There's no magic wand here.