# How to call a Method with DoWorkEventArgs args

Tags: c#, fingerprint

I'm trying to call this method from another one, but I don't how to call it, because it requires the arguments, and I don't know what to send them.

```
private void doVerify(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args) {
        VerificationResult verificationResult = new VerificationResult();
        verificationResult.score = _engine.Verify((NffvUser)args.Argument, 20000, out verificationResult.engineStatus);
        args.Result = verificationResult;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending Arguments To Background Worker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807152/sending-arguments-to-background-worker)

Answer (score 1):

The argument is what you pass into `RunWorkerAsync`.

See MSDN on [How to: Run an Operation in the Background](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hybbz6ke.aspx) for more info.

From what you posted you will do something like `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(myNffvUser);`.

Comment: mmm what is RunWorkerAsync?

Comment: doVerify.RunWorkerAsync(myNffvUser)?