# Sending a class pointer to background worker?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have made a small application that should download files from a website. I have a btn called `btnDownload_Click`. When it is clicked, a `BackgroundWorker` is created in order to keep the `form` functioning for the user while running the program. It then calls the `void Downloadfiles(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)` in order to download the file, with a bunch of settings specified in a `struct` called `DownloadSettings`.

The code for `btnDownload_Click` is shown below:

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //settings from the user (mostly)
            DownloadSettings settings = new DownloadSettings();
            settings.cond = txtSearchTerm.Text;
            settings.count = Int32.Parse(txtNumberofStudies.Text);
            settings.outputpath = txtFilePath.Text;
            settings.fmt = cmbFormats.Text;
            settings.flds = 10000;

            if (settings.outputpath == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select an output directory.", "Output directory needed");
            }

            else
            { 
                //https://stuff.seans.com/2009/05/21/net-basics-do-work-in-background-thread-to-keep-gui-responsive/
                SetAppState(AppStates.DownloadingFile);
                // Set up background worker object & hook up handlers
                _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                _worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Downloadfiles);
                _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
                _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                _worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgWorker_ProgressChanged);

                // Launch background thread to do the work of reading the file.  This will
                // trigger BackgroundWorker.DoWork().  Note that we pass the filename to
                // process as a parameter.

                _worker.RunWorkerAsync(settings);
            }
        }
```

My problem is that I cannot use `settings` as an argument in `Downloadfiles`:

```
        private void Downloadfiles(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) //string cond, string fmt, string outputpath
        {
            DownloadSettings settings = e.Argument as DownloadSettings;
        }
```

I just get the error `The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('DownloadSettings' is a non-nullable value type)`. How can I solve this? I got the idea for this solution from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29011429/7502962

Comment: Did you try `(DownloadSettings)e.Argument`? `as` won't work because it usually sets null (default) when the type doesn't match, and struct don't allow this.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work!